# How to know the datatype of input text in excel sheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check datatype of entered text in c#

**What I have done**

```
      if (!row.IsNull(dt.FieldCaption))
      {
          string value = row[dt.FieldCaption].ToString();
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
          {                               
              switch (dt.DataType.ToLower())
              {
                  case "int":
                      int v = 0;
                      int.TryParse(value, out v);

                      return true;

                  default:
                      return false;
              }
          }
      }
```

I'm unable to return the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! What do you mean "the datatype of entered text" ? What is your input variable ?

Comment: What you mean _"I cant able to return the value."_?

Comment: Which "value" do you mean to return? The `true`/`false` or the parsed `v` (that you don't need to parse, just cast, when you found that the datatype is "int")

Comment: Are you sure the datatype is "int" and not "System.Int32", which is the official name?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the result of TryParse?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I want to return parsed v

Comment: Show me the method signature. To return parsed v you should just return it like return v; :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking about the DataTable.

To get the cell values you can do something like that:

```
  for(int i = 0; i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <dt.Columns.Count ; j++)
    {
        object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
        //if you want to get the string
        //string s = o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
    }
```

Than you should know what kind of types are suppose to be stored in the your cells.

Or you can implement a function to convert string to a type:

```
int toReturnInt;
if (int.TryParse(s, out toReturn))
{
  return toReturnInt
}

bool toReturnBool;
if (bool.TryParse(s, out toReturnBool))
{
  return toReturnBool
}
```

"Datatype" of cell values

```
      if (!row.IsNull(dt.FieldCaption))
          {
              string value = row[dt.FieldCaption].ToString();
              if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
              {                               
                   bool toReturnBool;
                   bool toReturnInt;
                   if (int.TryParse(value, out toReturnInt))
                   {
                      // Datatype int
                      return toReturnInt;
                   }
                   else if (bool.TryParse(value, out toReturnBool))
                   {
                      // Datatype bool
                      return toReturnBool;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     // assume that it's string.
                     return value;
                   }
              }
          }
```

Comment: I want datatype of cell values

Comment: From my second example you can get cell value type. For a first case it's int and for a second it's bool.  you can return type as return typeof(int)  or return typeof(bool)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to read the Excel sheet using OLEDB. If that is the case, your code seems to be returning correctly the value after the call to

```
dt.DataType.ToLower()
```

in your `switch` statement. However, it looks like you are checking for the wrong value in your `case` statement. Instead of `"int"`, you should be checking for one of the values of the OleDbType (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum.

I would try something similar to the following code (even if the return part seems strange to me, probably you have to handle the result of this code differently from what you are currently doing):

```
switch (dt.DataType)
{
    case OleDbType.Integer:
        int v = 0;
        int.TryParse(value, out v);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```